How to get waveform and duration for JDA
I am using the following code to send an audio message to a Discord channel:
MediaType mt = MediaType.get("audio/mp3");
String wf = "VAIAAAAAAAAAADZ+W0teImse";
attachment = FileUpload.fromData(new File(filePath))
    .asVoiceMessage(mt, wf.getBytes(), 30);

Everything works fine, but waveform and duration is hard coded. Is anybody can help how to get this parameters correctly?
Is there any simple solution or do I have to use audio libraries like JavaZoom JLayer, Jaudiotagger,  TarsosDSP + FFmpeg?

According to the Discord Developer Documentation: "The waveform is intended to be a preview of the entire voice message, with 1 byte per datapoint encoded in base64. Clients sample the recording at most once per 100 milliseconds, but will downsample so that no more than 256 datapoints are in the waveform." - I think the Base64 encoding would probably be handled by JDA for you so you'd just need to provide the raw binary data of it.
